# How can I short php code?

Tags: php

How can i modify my code to work "smarter" without so many if-loops? I am attaching what i have tried so far.

```
$error1 = $error2 = $error3 = $error4 = $error5 = $error6 = $error7 = $error8 = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
      $error1 = "fill in fname";
    }  
    if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
      $error2 = "fill in lname";
    } 
    if (empty($_POST["street"])) {
      $error3 = "fill in street";
    }  
    if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
      $error4 = "fill in city";
    } 
    if (empty($_POST["postcode"])) {
      $error5 = "fill in postcode";
    } 
    if (empty($_POST["country"])) {
      $error6 = "fill in country";
    } 
    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
      $error7 = "fill in email";
    } 
    if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
      $error8 = "fill in phone";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For example instead 8 variables `$error1`, `$error2` etc you could create array of errors `$errors = [];` and add errors to that array in your if statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$errors = array();
$inputs = array("fname", "lname", "street", "city", "postcode", "country", "email", "phone");
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $arg) {
        if(in_array($key, $inputs) && empty($arg)){
            $errors[] = "fill in " . $key;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this

```
$formfields = array('fname','lname','street','city','postcode','country','email','phone');
$errMsg = "";
 if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)>0){
    foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
        if(in_array($key, $formfields)){
            if (empty($_POST[$key])) { $errMsg[] = "fill in ". $key; }  
        }
    }
 }

 if(count($errMsg)>0)
    echo implode("<br/>",$errMsg);
```